# Insert multiple strings into a string without adjusting for index changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

The conundrum I have is as follows: I have an array of the pair of indexes of a string at which one character (the third item in the sub-arrays) must be inserted (note, these pairs can be duplicates), e.g.

```js
let arr = [[0, 6, "7"], [0, 6, "h"], [2, 10, "2"], [12, 17, "j"]];

let my_string = "This is a very important string";

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // magic code
}

// => my_string now equals "7hth2is i7hs a 2vejry imjportant string";
```

I can't just insert the character at each index because the next pair of indexes in the array will become out of date, due to the previous pair of indexes changing the string and so causing it to have new indexes for each character.

I've also tried slicing the string based on the index pairs (using them as the start and end indexes) and inserting the characters onto these substrings before merging them all together again, but the issue with this is that if two pairs of indexes overlap, then parts of the original string get duplicated.

**NOTE**: the array is sorted in order from smallest second index in the pair to largest, as shown above. This can be changed. However, the array will always contain pairs of indexes - i.e. I cannot flatten the array into just indexes because of the third item of the arrays being the character I want to insert.

One other thing I tried was going from the end of the array of index pairs to the start, but again the fact that index pairs can overlap means this does not work.

How would I insert the characters at each index in the array of index pairs?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: flatten arr to a 1 dimensional array, sort it in descending order, and then loop as normal

Comment: @dementis I should have been more specific originally - I've updated my question to represent the fact that each pair of indexes is accompanied by the character that they insert

Comment: You say the expected output is `"7hth2is ih7s a 2vejry imjportant string"`, but that's inserting the `h` at index 6 *before* the `7` which also gets inserted at index 6? Is that intentional (if so, what are the rules), or a typo?

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry, that was indeed a typo. I'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an object of indicies containing strings, where each string item specifies the string to insert at that index. Eg, from

```
[[0, 6], [0, 6], [2, 10]]
```

and an array of characters to insert `['x', 'y', 'z']`, construct

```
{
  0: 'xy',
  2: 'z',
  6: 'xy',
  10: 'z'
}
```

Then you can use a regular expression to match any position (without matching any characters), and use its callback function to look up the current index on the object, and replace with all the characters at that point (if any):

```js
let arr = [[0, 6, "7"], [0, 6, "h"], [2, 10, "2"], [12, 17, "j"]];
const obj = {};
for (const [left, right, char] of arr) {
  obj[left] = (obj[left] || '') + char;
  obj[right] = (obj[right] || '') + char;
}
const my_string = "This is a very important string";

console.log(
  my_string.replace(
    /(?:)/g,
    (_, index) => obj[index] || ''
  )
);
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified (I will edit the question) - what I meant was one of the constraints is that the array will always have pairs, because in my real world code each pair of indexes are paired because they each represent a different type of character being inserted. E.g. the first pair will insert '7', the second will insert '2' etc.

Comment: Please show the data structure that indicates the different characters to be used

Comment: I've updated the answer, the nested arrays contain a third item which is the character to be inserted

Comment: Did you try the code in my answer? It looks to produce the output you want

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through the array you can loop through the string.

```js
let arr = [[0, 6, "7"], [0, 6, "h"], [2, 10, "2"], [12, 17, "j"]];

let my_string = "This is a very important string";

let str2 = ''
for (let i = 0; i < my_string.length; i++) {
  str2 += arr.filter(x => x.includes(i))
             .reduce(( total, current) => total + current[2],'') + my_string[i];
}

console.log(str2);
```

The `filter` will keep those elements in `arr` that contains the current index (`i`) of the loop.

If the `filter`'s output is not empty then `reduce` will concatenate all their 3rd elements. Finally the current `my_string` element is added at the end.

If the `filter`'s output is empty, `reduce` will do nothing, so only the current character in `my_string` is concatenated to `str2`.

The result:

```
7hTh2is i7hs a 2vejry imjportant string
```

Comment: This does has `O(n ^ 2)` complexity though, since you have to loop through each element (and nested element) of the array for every character of the string

Comment: @CertainPerformance The OP did not ask for a performing algo. And it's complexity is O(n*m) where n is the number of elements in the array and m the length of the string.